# How to Package an Erlang App?

Tags: erlang, package

What is the idiomatic way of packaging erlang modules/app? For example, in Java there two options: `jar` or `war` depending on deployment target.

Comment: Relevant: http://alancastro.org/2010/05/01/erlang-application-management-with-rebar.html

Answer (score 3):

In Erlang, modules are grouped into [applications](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/application.html). Applications are grouped into [releases](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_structure.html). How does this works? Like [this](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/release-is-the-word).

Luckily, [Rebar](https://github.com/basho/rebar) exists to do most of it. Rebar is probably the most commonly used tool to manage applications and releases.